# How to i Combine Front and back leaf Textures that is not alpha From Cgbookcase.com with Maps. on a Leaf plane front and back with two uv Map?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, eevee-render-engine, uv-image-editor

[image: Front and Back Leaf Texture no alpha]

I have two UV Maps on the mesh but I can not get UV map 2 to show at the bottom for the back of the leaf its a plane-shaped leaf...

Answer (score 1):

[image: result]

Use the *Backfacing* property from the *Geometry* node to mix the front and back textures.

Use the alpha of any texture as usual.

[image: node setup]